# Confusion about open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $Z \subseteq Y$. Let $f: (X, \tau) \to (Y, \tau')$ and $g: (X, \tau) \to (Z, \tau')$ be given by the same rule.

We say(?) $\tau'$ induces a topology on $Z$ s.t. $Z \cap V$ is open in $Z$ for any open $V \in Y.$

From here my book concludes $g^{-1}(Z \cap V) = f^{-1}(V).$ If this equality is true we can conclude $f$ is continuous iff $g$ is continuous.

Not sure about the equality, though.

Suppose $Z = (3, 5), V = (2, 7), f(x) = g(x) = x^2$. Then $g^{-1}(Z \cap V) = g^{-1}(2, 5)= (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 5)$ and $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(2, 7) = (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 7).$

Assuming the calculations above are correct, how does the equality above hold? Am I implicitly assuming some wrong things here? Thanks.

edit: changed $(3, 3)$ to $(3, 5)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(3,3)?$ That is either an empty interval, or a single point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in not defining $X.$

If $\sqrt 7\in X,$ then $g:X\to Z$ is not well defined, since $g(\sqrt 7)=7\notin Z.$

The whole point is that, while $f:X\to Y,$ we always have, for every $x\in X$ that $f(x)=g(x)\in Z.$

A typical example might be $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and $Z=\mathbb R^{\geq0}$ and $f(x)=g(x)=x^2.$

Comment: Can we prove the inequality? Suppose $x \in g^{-1}(Z \cap V)$. Then $$g(x) \in Z \cap V \\ \implies g(x) \in V \text{ and } g(x) \in Z \\ \implies x \in g^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(V) \text{ and } x \in f^{-1}(Z) \\ \implies x \in  f^{-1}(V) \cap f^{-1}(Z) \\ \implies x \in f^{-1}(V)$$ In the other direction, $x \in f^{-1}(V) \iff f(x) \in V \iff \ldots$ How do we get $f(x) \in V \cap Z \iff x \in f^{-1}(V \cap Z)$?

Comment: What inequality?

Comment: You get $f(x)=g(x)\in Z$ so $f(x)\in V\cap Z.$

Comment: Sorry, I meant equality. Is the other direction correct? Thanks.